# How to upload files to API in a form with React/MUI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a back-end application set up to accept data with an image, but cannot send an image through the front-end.

Here's the code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from '../../config';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import TextField from '@mui/material/Textfield';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

const Create = () => {
    const [form, setForm] = useState({});
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    
    const handleForm = (e) => {
        let name = e.target.name;
        let value = e.target.value;

        setForm(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            [name]: value
        }));
    };

    const isRequired = (fields) => {
        let error = false;

        fields.forEach(field => {
            if(!form[field]){
                error = true;
                setErrors(prevState => ({
                    ...prevState,
                    [field]: {
                        message: `${field} is required!!!!`
                    }
                }));
            }
        });

        return error;
    };

    const submitForm = () => {
        console.log("submitForm called")
        
        if(!isRequired(['title', 'image'])){
            let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            console.log("isRequired passed")

            axios.post('/movies', form, {
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                navigate('/movies');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
                console.log(err.response.data.message)
                setErrors(err.response.data.errors);
            });
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <h2>Create</h2>

            <div className='form-group'>
                <TextField 
                    variant='filled' 
                    label='Title' 
                    name='title' 
                    onChange={handleForm}
                    error={errors.title}
                    helperText={errors.title?.message}
                />
            </div>
            <div className='form-group'>
                <input
                    label='Image' 
                    name='image' 
                    accept="image/*"
                    //className={'form-group'}
                    style={{ display: 'none' }}
                    id="raised-button-file"
                    //multiple
                    type="file"
                />
                <label htmlFor="raised-button-file">
                    <Button variant="raised" component="span" className={'form-group'}>
                        Upload
                    </Button>
                </label>
            </div>

            <Button onClick={submitForm} variant='contained'>Submit</Button>
        
        </>
    );
};

export default Create;
```

When I try to submit the form, nothing happens. At first I thought it wasn't calling 'submitForm', but I added some console logs and found that it is calling it, but doesn't get into 'isRequired'. If I remove the image requirements, the form submits fine. I couldn't find a simple way to upload files using MUI in a form, not sure if there is one.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong/how I can do it right?

Let me know if there's any other information or code I can provide, any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uploading files is typically done through the use of [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) and sending a "multipart/form-data" content-type header.

But I recommend not trying to do this yourself and rely on a library to do it for you as there are always many factors to take into account when building a real-life upload flow.

I recommend [Uploady](https://react-uploady.org) for its simplicity and small footprint (and also [maybe] because I wrote it) -

Here's an example code for how to achieve something similar with Uploady.
Taken from this [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-uploady-inside-form-ys1wx?file=/src/App.js)

The code below shows how to combine normal fields (like name) with a file-selection button that will allow the user to choose the file to upload.

Notice that with a library like Uploady you can then enable many features easily such as filtering based on file type, progress indication, upload previews, etc.

```js
const MyUploadField = asUploadButton(
  forwardRef(({ onChange, ...props }, ref) => {
    const [text, setText] = useState("Select file");

    useBatchAddListener((batch) => {
      setText(batch.items[0].file.name);
      onChange(batch.items[0].file.name);
    });

    useBatchFinishListener(() => {
      setText("Select file");
      onChange(null);
    });

    return (
      <div {...props} ref={ref} id="form-upload-button" title={text}>
        {text}
      </div>
    );
  })
);

const MyForm = () => {
  const [fields, setFields] = useState({});
  const [fileName, setFileName] = useState(null);
  const { processPending } = useUploady();

  const onSubmit = () => processPending({ params: fields });

  const onFieldChange = (e) => {
    setFields({
      ...fields,
      [e.currentTarget.id]: e.currentTarget.value
    });
  };

  return (
    <Form>
      <MyUploadField autoUpload={false} extraProps={{ onChange: setFileName }} />
      <br />
      <input
        onChange={onFieldChange}
        id="field-name"
        type="text"
        placeholder="your name"
      />
      <br />
      <SubmitButton
        id="form-submit"
        type="button"
        onClick={onSubmit}
        disabled={!fileName}
      >
        Submit Form
      </SubmitButton>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Uploady
        clearPendingOnAdd
        destination={{ 
          url: "[upload-url]",
          headers: {
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}` 
          },
        }}
        multiple={false}
      >       
        <MyForm />
      </Uploady>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've been playing around with this for a couple of hours, but I can't get it to work at all. The application can't resolve '@rpldy/uploady-button' so I can't use 'asUploadButton', and any attempts at partial implementation with what I already have hasn't worked either

Comment: You wrote "@rpldy/uploady-button" while it should be "@rpldy/upload-button". Could that be the issue?

Comment: Ahh sorry, was a typo mistake just here, I was using "@rpldy/upload-button", but I did discover that my mistake was equally silly, I hadn't installed the specific package. In your code example, where are you importing 'Form' and 'SubmitButton' from?

Comment: check out the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-uploady-inside-form-ys1wx?file=/src/App.js) mentioned in the answer. These are just styled components I used so they look nicer than the simple HTML ones.

Comment: Ahh, I missed that you were creating the Form and SubmitButton there in file. Ok, I've got the application successfully up and running with this now for the first time, now to try and actually successfully submit something

Comment: Ok, I think there's one thing stopping it from working now. I'm using multer to accept the image in the back-end, but I'm getting a MulterError: unexpected field. I had tried to add the field like this in the <MyUploadField> tag in the form: https://imgur.com/a/7FR2Y93, but it didn't work. Is there maybe some other way I'm supposed to declare the field using Uploady?

Comment: Ahh, I found how to do it with inputFieldName, and it just succesfully uploaded an entry to the server! Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it. Thanks for creating the library also, it's very helpful.